# Insert statement not working when calling stored proc from C# code behind

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have a stored procedure in my database which inserts data to 3 tables. The procedure is compiled correctly. I have tested it with PL/SQL DEVELOPER tool with sample data & it is working fine.

In the code of stored procedure I have used a variable successCnt1 which counts the no. of successful insertion statements. This variable then assigned to successCnt. I am taking the value of this variable from code behind. If successCnt == 0 then an error is shown.

**Problem is** when I am calling it from C# code behind the procedure returns successCnt == 0. Please show me where I have done wrong!! Thanks in advance.

***Table Schema:***

**TBLTRAIN Schema:** {TRAINID (VARCHAR2(5)), DATE1 (DATE) , AC2SEAT (NUMBER) ,AC3SEAT (NUMBER) , SLEEPERSEAT (NUMBER) ,ACCHAIRCARSEAT (NUMBER) ,SECONDSEAT (NUMBER)}

**TBLTRAINFARE Schema:** {TRAINID (VARCHAR2(5)), CLASS (VARCHAR2(5)), FARE (NUMBER)}

**TBLTRAINDETAIL Schema:** {TRAINID (VARCHAR2(5)) , FROM1 (VARCHAR2(15)), TO1 (VARCHAR2(15)) , TRAINNAME (VARCHAR2(15)) }

***The Procedure:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TrainInsertByParameter (p_ac2seat   in number,
                                       p_ac3seat  in number,
                                       p_ccseat  in number,
                                       p_sleeperseat  in number,
                                       p_secondseat  in number,
                                       p_date1      in date,
                                       p_trainid   in varchar2,
                                       p_fare in number,
                                       p_fromplace in varchar2,
                                       p_toplace in varchar2,
                                       p_class in varchar2,
                                       p_trainname in varchar2,
                                       p_successCnt  out number)  IS
successCnt1 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
rowUpdated1 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
rowUpdated2 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
rowUpdated3 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;

BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT before;

  INSERT INTO tbltrain (ac2seat,ac3seat,acchaircarseat,sleeperseat,secondseat,date1,trainid) VALUES(p_ac2seat,p_ac3seat,p_ccseat,p_sleeperseat,p_secondseat,p_date1,p_trainid);


rowUpdated1 := SQL%RowCount;
successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;

   dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrain. count ='||successCnt1);
   dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrain. Row Updated ='||rowUpdated1);

  INSERT INTO tbltraindetail (trainid,trainname,from1,to1) VALUES(p_trainid,p_trainname,p_fromplace,p_toplace);


rowUpdated2 := SQL%RowCount;
successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;

 dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltraindetail. count ='||successCnt1);
 dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltraindetail. Row Updated= '||rowUpdated2);

INSERT INTO tbltrainfare(trainid,class,fare) VALUES (p_trainid,p_class,p_fare);

rowUpdated3 := SQL%RowCount;
successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;
p_successCnt := successCnt1;

 COMMIT;

 dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrainfare. count ='||p_successCnt);
 dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrainfare. Row Updated= '||rowUpdated3);

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN Others THEN
      successCnt1 := 0;
      p_successCnt := successCnt1;
      dbms_output.put_line('An error has occured. count ='||p_successCnt);

    ROLLBACK TO before;

END;
```

***Calling Code of C# Code Behind (using Microsoft Visual Studio))***

```
OracleConnection con1 = new OracleConnection();
                 con1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionStringOracle"].ConnectionString;

            Int32 fare = Convert.ToInt32(txtFare.Value);
            String date1 = txtDate.Value.ToString();
            String class1 = ddlClass.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            String fromplace = txtFromPlace.Text.ToString();
            String toplace = txtToPlace.Text.ToString();
            String trainid = txtId1.Text.ToString();
            String trainname = txtTrainName.Text.ToString();
            Int32 ac2seat = Convert.ToInt32(txtAc2TierSeat.Value);
            Int32 ac3seat = Convert.ToInt32(txtAc3TierSeat.Value);
            Int32 ccseat = Convert.ToInt32(txtAcChairCarSeat.Value);
            Int32 sleeperseat = Convert.ToInt32(txtSleeperSeat.Value);
            Int32 secondseat = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecondSeat.Value);
            Int32 SuccessCnt;

 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con1;
                    cmd.CommandText = "TrainInsertByParameter";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ac2seat", OracleType.Number).Value = ac2seat;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ac3seat", OracleType.Number).Value = ac3seat;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ccseat", OracleType.Number).Value = ccseat;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_sleeperseat", OracleType.Number).Value = sleeperseat;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_secondseat", OracleType.Number).Value = secondseat;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_date1", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_trainid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = trainid;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_fare", OracleType.Number).Value = fare;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_fromplace", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fromplace;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_toplace", OracleType.VarChar).Value = toplace;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_class", OracleType.VarChar).Value = class1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_trainname", OracleType.VarChar).Value = trainname;


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_successCnt", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                    try
                    {


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        SuccessCnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["p_successCnt"].Value);

                        if (SuccessCnt == 0)
                        {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Window", "alert('An error has occured. No data has been inserted. Please try again with valid data');", true);

                        }
                        else if (SuccessCnt > 0)
                        {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Window", "alert('Data has been inserted successfully.');", true);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
```

***My Prob is here:*** While I am debugging, in if-else block (inside the try{} block) the control always go to the if(SuccessCnt==0){} section, because the procedure returns p_successCnt ==0 . What I am expecting the control goes to 
else if(SuccessCnt > 0){} block because the procedure should return p_successCnt ==3

Comment: @Mat I am not getting any error in C#. I am getting some exception (which I dont know) in the stored procedure while it is called from code behind..But when I tested this procedure by writing a small PL/SQL calling code with some data it runs fine.. That is the problem.. And I will keep in mind what you have said about caps heading.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding output parameters to your procedure to give you back the SQLCODE and SQLERRM values resulting from any exceptions which occur when your procedure executes.  This way you can check for successful completion by checking for SQLCODE = 0.  Suggested changes are marked with an `-- added` comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TrainInsertByParameter (p_ac2seat   in number,
                                       p_ac3seat  in number,
                                       p_ccseat  in number,
                                       p_sleeperseat  in number,
                                       p_secondseat  in number,
                                       p_date1      in date,
                                       p_trainid   in varchar2,
                                       p_fare in number,
                                       p_fromplace in varchar2,
                                       p_toplace in varchar2,
                                       p_class in varchar2,
                                       p_trainname in varchar2,
                                       p_successCnt  out number,
                                       p_sqlcode out number,    -- added
                                       p_sqlerrm out varchar2)  -- added
IS
  successCnt1 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
  rowUpdated1 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
  rowUpdated2 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;
  rowUpdated3 number(6) NOT NULL := 0;  
BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT before;

  INSERT INTO tbltrain
    (ac2seat,ac3seat,acchaircarseat,sleeperseat,secondseat,date1,trainid)
  VALUES
    (p_ac2seat,p_ac3seat,p_ccseat,p_sleeperseat,p_secondseat,p_date1,p_trainid);


  rowUpdated1 := SQL%RowCount;
  successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrain. count ='||successCnt1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrain. Row Updated ='||rowUpdated1);

  INSERT INTO tbltraindetail
    (trainid,trainname,from1,to1)
  VALUES
    (p_trainid,p_trainname,p_fromplace,p_toplace);

  rowUpdated2 := SQL%RowCount;
  successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltraindetail. count ='||successCnt1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltraindetail. Row Updated= ' || rowUpdated2);

  INSERT INTO tbltrainfare(trainid,class,fare) VALUES (p_trainid,p_class,p_fare);

  rowUpdated3 := SQL%RowCount;
  successCnt1 := successCnt1 + 1;
  p_successCnt := successCnt1;

  COMMIT;

  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrainfare. count ='||p_successCnt);
  dbms_output.put_line('Successful Insertion tbltrainfare. Row Updated= '||rowUpdated3);

  p_sqlcode := 0;     -- added
  p_sqlerrm := NULL;  -- added
EXCEPTION
  WHEN Others THEN
    p_sqlcode := SQLCODE;  -- added
    p_sqlerrm := SQLERRM;  -- added

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || p_sqlcode || ' ' || SQLERRM);  -- added

    successCnt1 := 0;
    p_successCnt := successCnt1;
    dbms_output.put_line('An error has occured. count ='||p_successCnt);

    ROLLBACK TO before;    
END;
```

IMO returning SQLCODE and SQLERRM from any PL/SQL procedure which is called from another system is a good idea as it gives you a consistent method for determining if errors have occurred, and tells you what the error is.  YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I am new in PL/SQL.. I also wanted to see for what reasons the exception is happening, but don't know how to catch the error msg. Thanks for your fast reply.. I will try your code now, and will post back if the prob remain unsolved.

Comment: **Many many thanks!!** 

Using your added code I found my error & solved it.. The p_class1 value which I was passing was too large for the class field in my tbltablefare table.. That is why an exception was happening in the stored procedure. While I have tested it individually, my p_class1 value was small!! 

**Again many many thanks for your fast reply!!**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it personally myself, but I suspect you have to set the parameter size:

```
// cmd.Parameters.Add("p_successCnt", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleParameter count = new OracleParameter("p_successCnt", OracleType.Number);
count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
count.Size = 8;
cmd.Parameters.Add(count);
```

See also: [Oracle Store Procedure does not return any thing in the out parameter](http://forums.asp.net/t/1614727.aspx/1)

Comment: **Many many thanks for your code**.. Though parameter size may not be necessary if the out parameter is number but it is necessary when the out parameter is varchar. I have used Bob Jarvis 's code at first & then used your code & the error msg appears in my screen :).. Thanks for your help!!